# How to stub assets in Sprockets 4 without breaking everything?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, sprockets, precompile

I have a few different stylesheets that are supposed to be mutually exclusive, let's call them light.css.scss and dark.css.scss. Up until now, my asset pipeline consisted of:

Creating the files in the app/assets/stylesheets folder:

```
application.css
light.css.scss
dark.css.scss
```

Including them in my initializers/assets.rb:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( light.css.scss )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( dark.css.scss )
```

Stubbing them out in my application.css file:

```
/*
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
 *= stub dark.css.scss
 *= stub light.css.scss
 */
```

And then manually requiring them when needed:

```
<% if subdomain == "light" %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "light" %>
<% else %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "dark" %>
<% end %>
```

This worked great, but then I upgraded my Sprockets gem to 4.0, and everything broke. It turns out I need a assets/config/manifest.js file, but literally the only information I can find on that file is [this](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/29862), where the guy says he couldn't find any info on it either and that his app worked fine with a blank one. With a blank file, I'm getting errors like this:

```
#<ActionView::Template::Error: Asset `favicons/dark.png` was not declared to be precompiled in production.
```

implying the manifest file is responsible for precompiling all assets. But when I input the boiler plate code into it:

```
#manifest.js
//= link_tree ../images
//= link_directory ../javascripts .js
//= link_directory ../stylesheets .css
```

I get this:

```
#<ActionView::Template::Error: couldn't find file 'dark.css.scss' with type 'text/css'
```

And I get all sorts of similar unfound file errors no matter what I do. I don't get errors when I unstub the stylesheet files from my application.css, but then the styles all mix together and it's a design nightmare. I gather that application.css is "hiding" the files and then manifest.js is confused when it can't find them, but I don't know what to do about it. I tried unstubbing them from application.css and stubbing them in manifest.js, but that didn't work either. What's really weird is I can't find any information about how the manifest.js file is supposed to work.

Anyone know how I can keep my stylesheet files stubbed and not break my whole pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

The answer actually turned out to be pretty simple, the problem was the `require_tree .` in my application.css. I just deleted everything in it, and added my stylesheets one by one in manifest.js, using .css not .css.scss, like so:

```
//= link dark.css
//= link light.css
```

and then included the files as needed, as before. Now they're both precompiled but don't interfere with each other.